# Using malloc to allocate a stack for a thread in c, using SP to store context on stack

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc

I am designing a thread scheduler that needs to be able to swap the contexts of threads so that all the threads may run seemingly at once on a single thread NIOS-II Altera processor. I am using the Nios-II programmer with c to do this project. Currently, I am writing a function that creates a thread. What I need to do is use malloc to allocate a 4KB on the heap for each thread to act as its stack space. I then need to assign the thread's SP address value so that I can set it's initial context later on. I want to know, how do I get the top address of the malloc, as I am wanting to do:

SP = malloc's top address - 76

and store the thread's context at the top of the stack.

My current code:

```
struct TCB
{
    int thread_id; //number representing what thread this TCB belongs to
    int status; //running = 0, ready = 1, terminated = 2
    int executionInfo; //number of time this thread has been run      (incremented every time thread's context is restored)
    char* SP; //SP used to store and restore context (stw RA, 0(SP) -- stw R1, 4(SP))
};

void mythread_create(int thread_id){
    //use malloc to initialize stack space
    char* stack;
    stack = (char *) malloc(4000 * sizeof(char));

    //create and initialize TCB for thread
    struct TCB *TCB;
    TCB.thread_id = thread_id;
    TCB.status = 1;
    TCB.executionInfo = 0;
    TCB.SP =
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the malloc's "top address"?  Isn't that the address returned by the malloc() function?

Comment: I don't know. Is it? If so that answers my question, I guess.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner no, not with a stack that grows downwards, eg. on Intel hardware. The value returned by malloc is the base address and, to get to the top of the stack space, you have to add .the 4k to it.  swiley has it right and gets an upvote:)

Answer (score 3):

```
#define bufflen something
char *buf = malloc(bufflen*sizeof(char));
char *topaddress =(buf+bufflen);
char *sp = topaddress-76;
```